# Why is my account appearing on SO top users?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

When I view the [top users page for SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), my user account is right up top. However, I noticed that when I change the drop-down to select any other SE site, my account disappears from the list.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I think this seems a little odd. Is anyone else seeing their own account under SO top users?

Comment: Looks like it's 'king for a day' for everyone.

Comment: Because you're better than Jon and Marc, and you know it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Stack Overflow account appears at the top, but shows your ranking in relation to others. You are presently #12914 out of all qualified SO users.

Your other accounts all have less than 200 reputation. Leagues only track users with ~200 rep, which is why none of your other accounts are displayed.

Comment: This is correct.  The viewer is always displayed at the top for easy reference.