# Why do the rankings for the current period have me at the top when I am a lowly pleb?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

When I view the rankings for Stack Exchange, I am at the top for whatever is the current period (week, month, etc), which is obviously incorrect as I am not Jon Skeet :) However, if I view the immediately previous period I am not shown and all is right. Is this a bug? Or have I misunderstood the intended behaviour?

See for example the ordering by month rank for the current incomplete month August 2017:

[image: Sort by month rank for August 2017]

versus the previous month July 2017:

[image]

See also the ordering by rank change for the current incomplete week Aug 6 - Aug 6, 2017:

[image: Sort by rank change for week Aug 6 - Aug 6 2017]

versus the previous week Jul 30 - Aug 5, 2017:

[image: Sort by rank change for week Jul 30 - Aug 5 2017]

Comment: [tag:status-norepro]

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. Is there anything I should capture or check while my current session is alive to assist in determining whether this is a bug or a local glitch only affecting me?

Comment: Please don't modify the question once it has an answer in such a way that the answer no longer covers the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I don't know another way to add a new screenshot in response to an answer or comment - is there a better way I should use in future?

Comment: Ah, finally found that this has been asked before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110073/why-is-my-account-appearing-on-so-top-users

Comment: One difference, is that answer includes a comment "The viewer is always displayed at the top for easy reference." and as far as I can tell this isn't quite true: the viewer isn't displayed at the top when arriving at the ranking list from e.g. their profile. E.g. when I view the URL https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2017-08-06/428994 it does not does not display my profile at the top, but when I navigate forward and back in the list I am now displayed at the top (the URL is now https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2017-08-06?sort=reputationchange&page=3

Comment: If you have a new/follow up question, ask it separately.

Comment: I've rolled back my addition of the final screenshot that changed the question and accepted your answer - thanks! I'll move the follow-up questions to a new question.

Comment: Wow, wall of images... too much! But +1 for using the phrase "lowly pleb"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're logged in, the rankings show you at the top of each page if you have a ranking. On that first August 2017 page scroll down and click on page 2, you'll find you're still displayed at the top.

On July 2017 you don't have a rank because the ranking charts only record people with 200 rep or more and you had less than that at that time so you don't appear at all.

If you log out and then view the ranking charts you'll find you are not treated specially any more.

The prev/next buttons always start at page 1 rather than the page your profile is on (presumably so they work the same way whether or not you're logged in/exist etc). When you first see the list you're presumably starting from your profile which defaults to the page which you're on.

Comment: Ok, that sound reasonable, except that the first time I view the ranking list I am shown in the correct position in the list. If I then select the previous time period, I am not shown, as you suggest should happen, and when I then select the next time period (returning to the first list) I am now shown at the top of the list - is that the expected behaviour? I've attached another screenshot to show the "correct" positioning I see on the first viewing.

Comment: Ok, still reasonable, but...! ;) When I navigate through the list to find the page that has my profile, I am shown both at the top of the list and in the correct position, but when I directly arrive at the page of the list that has me on it, I am not also displayed at the top of the list. Is that also the intended behaviour? Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your input and am in no way trying to be argumentative - I just found the UI confusing and want to be sure that everything I'm seeing is "as intended" :)

Comment: How are you directly arriving at the page of the list?

Comment: From the “top xx% this week” link on my profile - this takes me directly to my position in the ranked list, without also having my entry at the top of the list. If I then choose “next” then “prev”, I come back to the page that has me in the list, as well as at the top this time.