# How am I at the top of this list?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

I have recently received some reputation which made me eligible for the association reputation where you get 100 reputation for every site you have account on stackexchange. 
I was just looking at the top userslist [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) and when I scrolled to the top, I saw my username. This is for all time. Also, this does not valid as it shows me in top 2% this month.

How is it possible that I am at this top of the list? Is it because it is designed to show the user currently logged-in at the top?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't see you at the top of the list. Can you post a screenshot? I see you as #387952 on the list.

Comment: ok, I think then it is because it is shown only to me

Comment: Related older posts: [Why is my account appearing on SO top users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110073) and [Why do the rankings for the current period have me at the top when I am a lowly pleb?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299389)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Those are similar, but not the same, my account appears for every period, from week to all time

Comment: See answer on dupe: "The leaderboard always shows your username/rep/rank on top before showing the rest of the leaderboard."

Comment: It is positioned at the top but it's not showing you ranked #1.

Comment: Also, this is the case, for some other sites as well.

Comment: @n8te, got you.

Comment: @KumarAnkit you appear in the list only in sites you have 200+ rep, right now only two: SO, and Movies.SE

Comment: It shows you at the top because you're awesome ... everyone is for that matter ....

Comment: @rene, Thanks for calling attention to the fact